# Awk: Count occurrences of negative values in each column and transpose CSV

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am trying to write an awk script that would create a list of countries that have a negative value in a column and count them:

**Sample data:**

```
COUNTRY NAME, SOCIAL SUPPORT, FREEDOM TO MAKE LIFE CHOICES, GENEROSITY, PERCEPTIONS OF CORRUPTION, POSITIVE AFFECT, NEGATIVE AFFECT, CONFIDENCE IN NATIONAL GOVERNMENT, DEMOCRATIC QUALITY, DELIVERY QUALITY
Afghanistan, 0.49, NULL, -0.11, 0.95, 0.49, 0.37, -0.26, -1.88, -1.43
Albania, 0.63, NULL, -0.03, 0.87, 0.66, 0.33, -0.45, 0.29, -0.13
Algeria, 0.80, NULL, -0.19, 0.69, 0.64, 0.34, 0.24, -0.92, -0.81
Argentina, 0.90, NULL, -0.18, 0.84, 0.80, 0.29, 0.30, 0.35, 0.15
```

**Desired Output:**

```
4 FREEDOM TO MAKE LIFE CHOICES: Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, Argentina
4 GENEROSITY:  Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, Argentina
3 DELIVERY QUALITY: Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria 
2 CONFIDENCE IN NATIONAL GOVERNMENT: Afghanistan, Albania 
2 DEMOCRATIC QUALITY: Afghanistan, Algeria
```

**My script (based on previous [answer from icarus on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684646/493832)):**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="," }

NR==1 { for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) { name[i]=$i } ; next } 
{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        v=$i+0
        if (v>0) continue;
        n=name[i]
        cnt[n]++
        cl[n] = cl[n]  $1  ","
    }
}
 

END { for (i in name) {
        n=name[i]   
        printf("%-2d %s: %s\n",cnt[n]+0, n, cl[n] );}}
```

1. My script does not only count the negative values but takes NULL and 0 into account.
2. I would like to sort the output by the count, but don't know how to do it in the END statement of the awk script.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you only want negative numbers, change the test from `if (v>0) continue` to `if (v>=0) continue`.

Comment: The fact that the above was not obvious suggests to me that you.are far from being able to write a sirt function in Awk. So I'd suggest that you pipe the output through `sort -nr` . I'm reasonably proficient in Aek, and I'd still pipe through `sory`; it's a lot less work.

Comment: Hey @rici! Thank you! I have been trying it out with v=>0. Yes, I am new to bash, and I  have been collecting information for this script for quite some time.  Thank you for the tips!

Comment: @rici on the other hand, even if (v>=0) continue, the script takes NULL values into account.

Comment: Ah, yes. NULL is not a number; moreover, the field starts with a space. Use `v+0 >= 0` to force numeric conversion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's 99% a duplicate of the OPs previous question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/684642/133219 and is mostly asking about the script they got as an answer there, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684646/133219.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use GNU awk, you can [control array traversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) with the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` setting:

```
#!gawk
BEGIN {FS = OFS = ", "}

NR == 1 {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) quality[i] = $i
    next
}

{
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i + 0 <= 0) {
            countries[i] = countries[i] OFS $1
            count[i]++
        }
    }
}

END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    for (i in count) {
        printf "%d %s: %s\n", count[i], quality[i], gensub(OFS, "", 1, countries[i])
    }
}
```

then

```sh
gawk -f script.gawk file.csv
```

outputs

```
4 FREEDOM TO MAKE LIFE CHOICES: Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, Argentina
4 GENEROSITY: Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, Argentina
3 DELIVERY QUALITY: Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria
2 CONFIDENCE IN NATIONAL GOVERNMENT: Afghanistan, Albania
2 DEMOCRATIC QUALITY: Afghanistan, Algeria
```